# "TypeError: failed to fetch" for api calls in Wso2 apim store

Tags: node.js, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have an nodejs api which gives a valid response in postman/browser. Tried to add the api in WSO2 api manager and followed the steps in the tutorials to succesfully publish the api in API Manager. But when created an product and using an auth token to call the created API getting the failed to fetch error as below:
[image]

Have tried enabling cors which didnt solve the issue. The api from the apim store isnt hitting the node server api.

Comment: i believe that's because https certifcate is not valid for your IP address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy and run that URL in a browser tab and accept the certificate. Then try again. It should work.

Comment: this is the workaround to solve this problem but what is the cause?

Comment: The default pack comes with a self-signed certificate, and the browser doesn't trust that. That's why you have to explicitly tell the browser to trust it.